# Sending input from one html form to several other html forms (client-side)

Tags: html, forms, client-side

I'm building an html web form, a log-in page which I want to be able to submit to a variable number of other web forms, depending on several check boxes.

The information passed would be user name and password, and the forms that I am passing them to are all on separate websites. These separate websites all have different names for these variables, and are not under my control.

The log-in information for one of these websites works for any of them, so the page I'm trying to make will basically compile multiple website log-in pages into one log-in interface, which the user enters their data and selects check boxes for each site they wish to open at that time. The sites would then need to open in new windows.

What I have right now is a page with multiple text fields, and submit buttons, which are on my website and successfully connect to the different sites.

Is it possible to create client-side code that will complete this task? Recording the user's log-in information into a database is not something I can do.

Comment: It feels a bit like the benefit of this multi-login functionality dwarfs in comparison with what may be needed to build it. Do you know whether you can authenticate users to the target sites via Ajax requests? Cloning the form on submit with Javascript/Jquery and using Ajax to send off the requests might be one possible avenue.

Comment: I do not know if Ajax requests would work. I have not used Ajax myself. I'll look for information on that, or if you had any particular links that would be wonderful.

Comment: I would Google for how to do an Ajax POST request using Ajax, and how to clone a form using Jquery, and then how to open the URLs in new windows... but I don't want to encourage to go on a wild goose chase. Not sure if it will work and if you haven't done it before, it's going to involve some hassle for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution just uses javascript.

I ended up using the method described here: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=100425

Using this, I could open up multiple pages at once from one link.

To fill in the forms I made one log-in, and changed all the other forms to hidden.

Then I used simple check boxes to control which pages were requested.

Right now my only issue is two of the pages need a cookie to validate before the form will go through. My fix for this while coding was simply to have the actual pages open well doing my testing.

Is there a way to request the cookie off a website, so I can hand it to the user as they submit their log-in info?

Comment: The page does not exist anymore.